# MYSQL:- How to distinguish between Ã©' and é french character

Tags: mysql

I have both the character 'Ã©'and 'é' in my Mysql database table record and wanted to convert only the french character like Ã© (UTF-8)

Using below query to find all the french character.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM <table> 
 where cid=2 
   And ((field01 LIKE binary'%Ã%') 
        OR 
        (field02 LIKE binary'%Ã%') 
        OR 
        (field03 LIKE binary'%Ã%')
       )
```

Getting Below OutPut :-

```
+---------+------------------------------------+---------+
| field01 | field02                            | field03 |
+---------+------------------------------------+---------+
| NULL    | Namé                               | NULL    |
| NULL    | L2Ã‡ais                            | NULL    |
| NULL    | L1Ã™Ã›ÃœÅ¸Ã€Ã‚Ã†Ã‡Ã‰ÃˆÃŠÃ‹ÃÃŽÃ”Å’  | NULL    |
+---------+------------------------------------+---------+
```

But I don't want first row with(é)and my select statement should show only last two rows with UTF-8 french character.

Any help how can i find the french character which are in UTF-8

```
(Ã©|Ã‡|Ã™|Ã›|Ãœ|Ã¸|Ã€|Ã‚|Ã†|Ã‡|Ã‰|Ãˆ|ÃŠ|Ã‹|ÃŽ|Ã”|Ã’)
```

Edit - column types and charsets:

```
 | Field   | Type         | Collation       | 
 | field01 | varchar(320) | utf8_unicode_ci | 
 | field02 | varchar(128) | utf8_unicode_ci | 
 | field03 | varchar(128) | utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your column type and charset?

Comment: This kind of problem is maddeningy difficult to debug. :-(

Comment: | Field            | Type             | Collation       |

| field01          | varchar(320)     | utf8_unicode_ci |  

| field02          | varchar(128)     | utf8_unicode_ci | 

| field03          | varchar(128)     | utf8_unicode_ci |

Comment: Would utf8mb4 fix this?

Comment: @Strawberry no, these characters are all supported also by utf8

Comment: @AshishChillure If my answer doesn't help, please give output of `SELECT @@character_set_client, @@character_set_results, @@character_set_connection;` to debug this further.

Comment: mysql> SELECT @@character_set_client, @@character_set_results, @@character_set_connection
    -> ;
+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| @@character_set_client | @@character_set_results | @@character_set_connection |
+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| latin1                 | latin1                  | latin1                     |
+------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+

Answer (score 0):

Your command works for me, so problem seems to be that `Ã` in your query is not encoded as UTF-8.

If `Ã` in your query is being encoded e.g. as ISO 8859-1 character, then it will become just `x'C3'` which will match both `é` (`x'C3A9'` in UTF-8) and `Ã` (`x'C383'` in UTF-8) because both have byte `x'C3'` in them.

Try using

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

before your command to make connection use UTF-8 encoding and make sure you send the SQL command as UTF-8 string from whatever client you are using.

Comment: That make sense, will try that. Thanks Markus

Comment: Tried that but the fields which is already having Ã© is getting converted to  ÃƒÂ© , this seem to be double utf8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Tried below conversion and didn't got first row with(é) and got only last two rows with UTF-8 french character.

(CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field01 USING latin1) USING utf8))

This worked for me.

Thanks
Ashish Chillure